# $and in spring data mongodb, spEl not supported in latest version? (2.2.6)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-el

Today I upgraded the version of my spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb from version 2.0.3 to version 2.2.6 (mongodb driver 3.6.4-> 3.11.2). Unfortunately I have errors that have occurred.

Before i used :

```
@Query("{$and :["
        + "?#{ [0] == null  ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'v1' : { $in : [0] } } },"
        + "?#{ [1] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'v2' : [1] } },"
        + "?#{ [2] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'v3' : [2]  } },"
        + "?#{ [3] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'v4' : [3] } },"
        + "?#{ [4] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'v5' : [4] } },"
        + "?#{ [5] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'v6' : { $in : [5] } } }"
        + "]}")
```

Now i get a error on $and expression :

```
EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'colon(:)'.
```

I used a simplified version without spEl expression and it works but I would like to continue using spEl in my queries because they are sometimes complex. Anyone have an idea of ​​the problem?

Comment: I've created [DATAMONGO-2523](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2523) to investigate the issue. Meanwhile would you please try to add an extra space (`+ " ]}")`) before closing the `$and` array.

Comment: A fix is on the way. [#859](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/859)

Comment: Thank you for your response and reactivity . An extra space was the solution for me.